# What happens to vertex shader `varying` variable with `highp` qualifier if high precision is unsupported in fragment shader?

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

In OpenGL ES 2.0 ([Shading Language 1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf)), does qualifying a `varying` vertex shader variable with the `highp` qualifier have any effect, such as on performance, if `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` is undefined?

For example, when `highp` is unavailable in the fragment language, would linking the following fragment shader with each of the following two vertex shaders, one at a time, result in equivalent programs?

Fragment:

```c
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
#else
varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;
#endif
...
```

Vertex 1:

```c
...
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main() {
    ...
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

Vertex 2:

```c
...
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
#else
varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;
#endif

void main() {
    ...
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

The section in the [GLSL ES 1.00 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) referring to `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` is 4.5.4.

Comment: version one will fail to compile / link

Comment: @gman are you sure? I tried setting it to `highp` in the vertex shader and `mediump` in the fragment shader (without the preprocessor check) with webgl in Firefox and it worked. Or is that because the hints have been ignored, since it's on desktop, and therefore there is no mismatch?

Comment: IIRC it will fail on machines that don't support highp. I know of no desktops for which this is true. You'll basically need an old phone to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is version one will fail to compile on machines that don't support highp in fragment shaders. Those are basically older phones. I'm not sure which generation of phones you'd have to use but I know most recent smartphones support highp in fragment shaders.

On desktops, in my experience, they always use highp even if you put mediump. Note that this is fine as far as the spec is concerned. The spec allows implementation to use higher precision then asked for.

On Mobile, at least as of 2018, most GPUs do actually support mediump and there will be a difference in performance. There will also be as specified only a mediump level of precision.

[Here's a small example](https://codepen.io/greggman/full/WMVdbz):

```js
// WebGL 3D Lathe Compute Normals
// from https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-3d-lathe-step-03.html

"use strict";

const vs = `
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = a_position;

  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform float u_scale;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texcoord * u_scale, 1, 1);
}
`;

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  twgl.setDefaults({attribPrefix: "a_"});

  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL programs
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  const size = 1/10000;
  
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    data: [
    -1, -1,
     1, -1,
    -1,  1,
     1,  1,
    ],
    numComponents: 2,
  },
  texcoord: [
    0, 0, 
    size, 0,
    0, size,
    size, size,
  ],
  indices: [
    0, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 3,
  ],
 });

  function update() {
    render();
  }
  update();

  function render() {
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas, window.devicePixelRatio);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Compute the projection matrix
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // Setup all the needed attributes.
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    // Set the uniforms
    // calls gl.uniformXXX, gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_scale: 1 / size,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements.
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  }

}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

This just draws a quad and interpolates values across the quad. The values go from 0 to 0.0001 and are then multiplied by 10000 to get values from 0 to 1.

Desktop using mediump (which my desktop GPU will actually use highp)

[image]

iPhoneX using mediump (which will actually use mediump)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `mediump` GPU support? I thought it was always available?

Comment: I mean that the GPU actually runs mediump at meduimp precision and not as highp precision. running mediump as highp is spec compatible but it does not help you test that your code will run on hardware that actually runs mediump at mediump precision

Comment: Sorry, I, mistakenly, thought the first and last paragraphs were slightly contradictory, but you mean that most of the current GPUs that support `highp` will obey the `mediump` precision hint, unlike on desktop?

Comment: most of the current mobile phones in 2018 that support highp will actually use mediump precision if something is marked as mediump in the shader unlike on desktop where marking something as mediump still gets you highp

Comment: Thanks for clarifying